# What to do If my answer is exact same answered by other user

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I have answered this question : [What is the use of <developers> tag in pom.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713254/what-is-the-use-of-developers-tag-in-pom-xml-file)

While answering this question, other user has just answered exact same answer I was writing and I posted.

Please tell what to do now as user commented that this answer is duplicate.

Comment: I don't see any action necessary.

Comment: Don't sweat it if it was unintentional. Both of your answer are duplicates of this one anyway, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19449239/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ Okay Cool then. Is there any action needed by moderator or by me?

Comment: @VaibhavMule, No.